# Associated owner group is always null

Tags: powershell, permissions, site-collection, groups

I am using PowerShell to create site collections, and add users by code. I add users as visitors, contributors and as owners. In my powershell code I can get both the Visitors and Contributors group, but Owners Group is always null.  I can not understand why. Please advice. This is my code snippet. $web.AssociatedOwnersGroup always returns null

```
function Add-UsersToSpGroup ( $url, $listItemUsers, $PermissionsGroup )
{  
    $web = Get-SPWeb $url
    $Users = $listItemUsers
    if($PermissionsGroup -eq "Owners")
    {
        $Group = $web.AssociatedOwnersGroup;
    }
    elseif($PermissionsGroup -eq "Members")
    {
        $Group = $web.AssociatedMemberGroup;
    }
...
}
```

I am using SP 2013 on-prem.

Comment: Did you check if the Owner group actually exist on your site collection first?
use this at the end of your url to see _layouts/15/permsetup.aspx

Comment: yep, it exists. What happens by clicking "ok" in here. Does it trigger "CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups" ?

Comment: my understanding the AssociatedOwnerGroup has to be null before invoking CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups method.  so you should do something like $web.AssociatedOwnerGroup = $null before $web.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups($web.Site.Owner.UserLogin, $web.Site.SecondaryContact.UserLogin, $web.Title)